# Difference between two ways of passing function as parameter

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

These two ways of defining a function accepting another function seem to work identically (as in, the body is the same for both functions). I found the first one by fiddling, and then found the second one on several websites.

```
void foo(int bar())
void foo(int (*bar)())
```

Example body:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      cout << bar() << ' ';
}
```

What's the difference? Is one preferred over the other? Is it compiler or C++ version dependent?

Comment: I think using a template argument instead is to be preferred, because that'll work with anything functiony - function pointers, lambdas, objects that overload `operator()`, etc. More opportunities for optimization too than if you restrict it to function pointers.

Answer (score 4):

They are identical, as per [function parameters declaration rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list).

> The type of each function parameter in the parameter list is determined according to the following rules:
>   ...
>   3) If the type is a function type `F`, it is replaced by the type "pointer to `F`"
>   ...

Comment: @SombreroChicken you might need some adjustment

Answer (score 1):

For me a preferable way is

```
void foo( int bar( void ) );
```

because a function declaration as a parameter looks more clear.

It is similar to writing whether

```
void f( int a[] );
```

or

```
void f( int * );
```

The first declaration gives the reader of the code the idea that the function accepts an array instead of a pointer to a single object.

For example

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
```

looks more clear then

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
```

In fact there is no difference because the compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter of a function type to pointer to the function type.

From the C++ 17 Standard (11.3.5 Functions)

> 5 The type of a function is determined using the following rules. The
>   type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is
>   determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator. After
>   determining the type of each parameter, **any parameter of type “array
>   of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”**....